# How to continue filling a form that has a vue datepicker cypress?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, cypress

I try to fill a form using cypress. That form is built with Vue and it looks like this

[image]

The problem is, dispatch date is a date picker that I fill using cypress type() command. For example

```js
cy.get('#dispatch-date').type('22-10-2022');
```

However, this is how the form looks like after the type command

[image]

the drop down menu of the date picker covers the rest of the form not allowing cypress to continue the form filling. I tried clicking {enter} after typing the date but it submits the form. I also tried the {force:true} option, but it makes the test fails because the datepicker is actually a <div> and not an <input> tag. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `.blur()` after your `.type()` command? If there's an error that the field isn't focused, try adding `.focus()` before `.type()` as well -> `focus().type('foo').blur()`... I'm unsure why or if this would even work, but `.blur()` has helped a lot when filling out fields.

Comment: @agoff Yes, I tried the blur and an error was also thrown because it is not an input tag I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend on the exact datepicker you have in the app, or more precisely the way the user interacts with it.

For example if it's the vue2-datepicker you can probably just tab off the control to trigger it's update.

```js
cy.get('#dispatch-date')
  .type('{selectAll}22-10-2022')                   // {selectAll} if not empty
  .trigger('keydown', {keyCode: 9, which: 9})

cy.get('#dispatch-date')
  .should('have.value', '22-10-2022')
```

Note a click on the `<body>` element will close the picker, but the value is not updated to v-model.